# Java Selenium Get Element for Click

Tags: java, selenium, automatic-ref-counting

i have some problems to get the  right element to perform a click.
I use selenium.

I want to click on the Log In "Button" on this page https://campus.uni-stuttgart.de/cusonline/webnav.ini

Maybe sb could help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code. The login button is available under a frame. so it is necessary to switch to that frame in order to access the element.

```
driver.get("https://campus.uni-stuttgart.de/cusonline/webnav.ini");
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@name='menue']")));
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#menue_frame_key_icon > img")).click();
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

Comment: thx for you Answer. But i have another Question. Now i want to type the username into a textbox. This Textbox is available under a form. Is it necessary to switch to that form ?

Comment: No need to switch to that forms. However I see another frame with name="detail". you need to switch to that frame before accessing your username textbox.

Answer (score 0):

It appear the login button id is "menue_frame_key_icon".

So this should be:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("menue_frame_key_icon")).click();
```

You could alternately try the child element of that id, which can be done multiple ways. This will work though:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#menue_frame_key_icon > img")).click();
```

Comment: thx for you answer. i tried both but nothing happens :/  package CampusPackage;


public class CampusCode {
 

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
 {

  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\SeleniumDrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
 WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
 driver.get("https://campus.uni-stuttgart.de/cusonline/webnav.ini");
 driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#menue_frame_key_icon > img")).click();
 


 System.out.println("Title:" + driver.getTitle());


 
 

 }
}